# List users/roles who has access to node

Tags: views, users

Asked this question on Drupal.org also, but i think this place is going faster and better :-)

I've installed Content Access and made a view for a Content Type. In the table, users can see content only for them. An admin is giving the rights to view, edit and delete content.

Is it possible to show to users who else has access to a node?

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question with *Views*. Are you asking whether it's possible to build a *View* to do that? If so, then the answer is **no** (unless there's some module or plug-in out there which would add that capability).

Views queries the database, but node access permissions can be set in code via [hook_node_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x). It's totally possible, for example to write some code that grants a user access to a specific node only if they have the letter 'x' in their name and today is Monday.

You can of course do it with some PHP code, and you could hook that into a View using [Views hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7.x-3.x). I'm not sure what the most efficient approach would be, but basically:

- Use [hook_views_post_execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7.x-3.x) to process the list of nodes returned by your View.
- For each node in your View result, you would need to loop through all users, calling [node_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access/7.x) to test if that user (uid) had access to the node or not.
- From the results, build a list of users who had access, and have Views display that list by modifying  the *$view* object that was passed to your hook function.